# Need to trigger a script to run on a specific date from a Unix hosted static website

Tags: unix

I have a static website running on a Unix hosting service where I need to trigger an event at a particular date which is calculated from a date (which changes regularly) written in a table on the site. The trigger will set an email send operation off. Is there a way to trigger the event from a script in the site or from the hosting platform? Or do I need to turn to a commercial programme to do this? (If so, which one)?
Grateful for your thoughts on this.
Cheers,
David

Comment: That's too broad, can you give an example at least, i.e. what do you add to what to get what, and what's the time scale we're talking?  "Tomorrow in 40 weeks", or more like "next Friday"?

Answer (score 0):

Well basically your options (from my own use cases) are:

1. Use `sleep(1)` for stuff that needs second or sub-second accuracy, spawned through your script and `nohup(1)`'d.
2. Use the `at(1)` command to schedule execution with the at-daemon (needs a running `atd`)

Option 1 can use relative times and works on any unix, this is `sleep-script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep "$@"
## dostuff
echo "DONE"
```

then from your script:

```
...
nohup sleep-script.sh 1m 19s &
...
```

Option 2 needs a running `atd` (and does support absolute times), in your script you'd put:

```
...
at 09:45 tomorrow <<EOF
## stuff i need done
echo "DONE"
EOF
...
```

Option 2 is more comfortable because you can use `atq` and `atrm` to see the queue of commands or remove specific jobs from the queue, respectively.  But it doesn't support sub-minute accuracy with the syntax above.

Comment: To give you a bit more specific information. I need to trigger a script to run which will send emails. The date for the script to run is calculated from a date (that is entered once about every 3 weeks as the year passes) minus 4 days. When "date-4" is reached, the script should be triggered and the emails sent.
My issue is how to calcualte the "date-4" from a static table containing the date on my website and create the trigger.
My query centres on how to calculate "date-4" and when it is found, then use the result to send the emails. It isn't important at what time on "date-4" they get sent.

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for taking the time to answer. Would the dateutils be able to run from a Unix platform that is hosting my website? In other words, do I have the ability on a hosting platform to access the command line?
The table I am referring to is a table that is actually and html table on a web page in which a date is entered for display. It isn't in an mySQL database or anything like that.
I'm guessing this is getting mighty complicated, but if it isn't am very grateful for the time you are taking to help me.
Cheers, David

Comment: I don't know your hosting provider, but yes, you would need to have shell access to install the package.  If you can only see/use php for instance, there would be a php-solution as well but I'm no php expert.  Out of interest, how do you start the script then on the hosting platform then?

Answer (score 0):

As I misread the question, here's another answer that deals with the actual date computation:

If you can extract the date so that command line tools can use it, there's a plethora of possibilities, [`dadd` from dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) for instance:

```
$ dadd 2014-01-27 -4
2014-01-23
```

Or even via stdin:

```
$ echo 2014-01-27 | dadd -4
2014-01-23
```

If by table you mean sql table, you could use the date arithmetic of your database system, e.g. in mysql:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE("2014-01-27", "%Y-%m-%d"), INTERVAL -4 DAY);
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE("2014-01-27", "%Y-%m-%d"), INTERVAL -4 DAY) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-01-23                                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

which can be run from the command line as well to pass on the value to tools like `at`.

Answer (score 0):

Again thanks for taking the time to answer. At present, I don't start the script that I'm referring to here. That's the current problem. Another script I use is a simple trigger from a submtted form. That wasn't too complicated. I guess I'll have to keep looking.
ALl the best,
David